# Using a global variable for any set /p value?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm currently creating a game written entirely in Batch. I'm curious if there's a way that I can globally set an option for any `set /p` function as a valid response.

For example, let's say that this is my script.

```
@echo off
title Test Script

:HELLO1
set /p hello1=ENTER "HELLO1"! 
if %hello1% == HELLO1 GOTO HELLO1_CONTINUE
goto HELLO1_ERROR

:HELLO2
set /p hello2=ENTER "HELLO2"! 
if %hello2% == HELLO2 goto HELLO2_CONTINUE
goto HELLO2_ERROR
```

I want both of these options to be able to use `exit` as an option to close the entire script, however I don't want to repeat `if %hello[#] == EXIT EXIT` twice, three times, or as many times as I have player options within the script, especially since each one has to be written in with each specific #, according to which `set /p` label I'm using.

Is there any way to go about this? Not opposed to using external libraries either.

I was thinking something along the lines of setting a variable equalling EXIT, for example, however I have 0 ideas on how I would actually implement that into the script.

Comment: Why not use `GoTo :EOF` instead of `goto SOMESTRING_ERROR`? If you wish to reduce repetition, you need to change from very basic `GoTo` syntax, and consider parenthesised blocks and `Call`'s with arguments if necessary.

Comment: You should also, if use `Set /P`, ensure that the user input is validated before you use it. At that prompt, the end user can type anything they want, or nothing at all before pressing the enter key. _(that includes any poison character(s) they wish too)_

Comment: I use `goto SOMESTRING_ERROR` as there are many different variables at play. Name, gender, age, race, class, ETC, and I would like to provide a different error messages for each string. 
For example, if a player inputs an invalid response for the gender (outside of M/F), instead of just displaying "this choice is invalid", I can send the script to a specific label which will then display specifically "this gender choice is invalid" Similarly with any other invalid string of text.

Comment: I used `goto SOMESTRING_ERROR` as my validation method, as anything not set in "if SOMETSTRING == SOMERESPONSE" will automatically send the player to the appropriate error label.

For example, if a user inputs anything outside of `HELLO2` as the response of the `set /p hello2=` input, it will automatically take them to `:HELLO2_ERROR`, instead of continuing with the script

Comment: I know what you used, but as I've already stated, that is simply not good enough. Take this command, `if %hello1% == HELLO1`, then imagine the expanded value of `%hello1%` being nothing. What will happen with the following command, `if == HELLO1`, or what about them typing `defined`,  or `&` or `>` or `|`, and believe me, it wouldn't be too difficult to enter something malicious either.

Comment: Currently, if a user inputs `&`, `>`, `|`, or `defined`, the program just closes. As well, this isn't a shared script. I.E, I'm not worried about mine, or anyone else's security. If someone entered something malicious, it would be their own computer they're hurting. I can see why character validation would be useful, say for example if we were using CMD to pull update files for an entire user group, and someone could potentially access something malicious. But the file is simply downloaded onto their computer, and they run it. If they do anything with ill intent, they're only hurting themself.

Comment: This is just a simple RPG game I'm making. If I were super worried about security, or malicious intent, I'd probably write it in another language, considering I can't even hash or encrypt player passwords ahaha.

Comment: `Set hello2=Hello2` and `set /p hello2=ENTER "%HELLO2%"!` and to fix your `if` statement - `if "%hello2%"=="HELLO2" goto HELLO2_CONTINUE`.

Comment: I'm in the midst of developing a very in depth batch RPG and have some very useful learnings to respond with when I have a bit more time

Comment: @Compo, _TBF_ I think it should be interpreted that I was talking more about responses regarding the original question at hand. I do appreciate the advice, and I'm sorry if my responses don't convey that. I think my point however is that this is just a small project, and it doesn't have to be, nor do I want it to be, perfect. There are already a lot of elements I'm learning, alongside what I'm learning here, and so implementing every single one (on a time-schedule restricted as mine) is very difficult. Sometimes prioritizing certain things is more important than fitting it all in at first.

Comment: @Mark What exactly does putting the variable in quotations do, if you don't mind me asking? I understand what if would do for something like `md "PROJECT/DATA/WHATEVER DIRECTORY"`, but I'm not sure exactly what the context of using them in this instance is?

@T3RR0R Very much appreciated. I don't think mine will be quite as fleshed out as yours, however I do expect to have quite a bit of content. If you're ever in the mood to spitball some ideas, or share some knowledge, it would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: If the user enters a blank then the code becomes `If ""=="Hello2` else it would be `if ==Hello2` which is illegal command, you have to have something both sides of the equals. Likewise spaces count `If %hello2% == Hello2` means If %Hello2%<space>==<space>hello2`,

Comment: https://pastebin.com/pgy7Rg17 and https://winsourcecode.blogspot.com/2019/12/command-prompt-cheat-sheet.html. Batch file is the wrong language. It won't scale.

Comment: It's a shame S.O. doesn't have a direct messaging service.
Happy to answer any question where I have the knowledge. There's alot I've Figured out - from Music and sound effect handling, basic ANSI facilitated animation, and being able do a crude 'install' that creates shortcuts and applies custom Icons to shortcuts and Folders.

Some of these things use other scripting Languages like vbs and Powershell, However all of those scripts are generated / launched from within my batch programs.

Comment: Chat room https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat-rooms

Comment: thanks for the tip there Mark, nice to know it's there... Once I've earned it.

Comment: @T3RR0R I've actually got a lot of that stuff myself. I use cmdmp3 as an audio engine, with a little custom script I've written, definitely have an installer (you can even pick and choose which options of the game you'd like to install, and it downloads it directly using WGET, moves the files into the correct folder, ETC, ETC), I could do shortcuts and such, but it's a bit silly IMO. I've actually not used VBS or Powershell yet. Haven't found a reason too.

Comment: @T3RR0R Do you have some sort of communication we could use that you'd be willing to share publicly? If not, no big deal, but I'd love to actually talk with you sometime :)

Comment: @Mark I see, so if you add the spaces it adds that to the character count. I see now. Definitely going to clean it up a little bit then.

Comment: Put this one lineer into a vbs file and turn volume up. `CreateObject("sapi.spvoice").speak "Hello T3RR0R and  Ian Hughes"`

Comment: I can be found here...
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCo3tS26Eg-ITbdNgWhB0MRQ

Comment: I've put up a new answer that is a better approach for what you want to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you make all your variables have a sufficiently unique prefix, you might be able to work something like this:

```
set hello1=test
set hello2=bob
set hello3=exit
set "hello4=exit=bot"
set "hello5=bob=exit"

for /f "delims== tokens=1*" %%a in ('set hello') do (
   if /i "%%~b"=="exit" exit
)

echo If you get here, exit not found.
```

Answer (score 0):

Definitely I'm not sure if I've understood this question, so...

- This basally follow your code layout

```bat
@echo off && setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 

set hello=<nul && title nul & title Test Script&& set/p "hello=ENTER "HELLO1" or "HELLO2"!! "
for %%S in (!hello!)do for /f %%n in ('cmd.exe /u /c echo="%%~S"^|find /v " " ^|findstr [0-9]
')do if %%~n geq 1 echo/!hello!|find/i "hello"|findstr "1 2" >nul && goto :hello%%~n_CONTINUE
echo/The "!hello!" is not a valid input option, only Hello1 or Hello2^!! && goto :HELLO_ERROR

:HELLO1_CONTINUE
echo/I'm in HELLO1_CONTINUE & goto :END

:HELLO2_CONTINUE
echo/I'm in HELLO2_CONTINUE & goto :END

:HELLO_ERROR
echo/Well, something is really wrong!! & goto :END

:END
endlocal && exit /b
```

Or, in another layout:

```bat
@echo off && @(setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion)

set _hello=<nul & title nul & title Test Script
set /p "_hello=Enter: "HELLO1" or "HELLO2"!!! "

for /f %%n in ('cmd/u/cecho="!_hello!"^|findstr [0-9]')do (
  echo/"!_hello!" |find /i "hello" |findstr "1 2" >nul && (
  goto:!_hello!_CONTINUE) || (set "_msg=Input Error^!!"&& (
  cmd /v/c echo/!_msg!&& timeout -1 && goto :HELLO_ERROR)))

:HELLO1_CONTINUE
echo/I'm in HELLO1_CONTINUE & goto:END

:HELLO2_CONTINUE
echo/I'm in HELLO2_CONTINUE & goto:END

:HELLO_ERROR
echo/Well, something is really wrong!!
goto :END

:END
endlocal && exit /b
```

For global option:

---

```bat
@echo off && @(setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion)

set _hello=<nul & title nul & title Test Script
set /p "_hello=Enter: "HELLO1" or "HELLO2"!!! "

for /f %%n in ('cmd/u/cecho="!_hello!"^|findstr [0-9]')do (
echo/ "!_hello!" | find /i "hello" |findstr "1 2" >nul && (
goto:%_hello:~,-1%_CONTINUE)||(set "_msg=Input Error^!!") )
cmd /v /c echo/!_msg! && timeout /t -1 && goto :HELLO_ERROR

:HELLO_CONTINUE
echo/I'm in !_hello!_CONTINUE & goto:END

:HELLO_ERROR
echo/Well, something is really wrong!!
goto :END

:END
endlocal && exit /b
```

Comment: Just a suggestion- When providing an answer, including notations explaining what things do and how / why will be of much more benefit in helping people asking questions to build their understaning of how to apply the solution to their problems and other similar problems in future.

To someone such as the OP, who is clearly still learning batch, this answer is going to be a bunch of jargon - a block of commands that a programmer new to batch wouldn't easily be able to intuit the function of.

Answer (score 0):

I think this approach more closely achieves what your asking for, my previous answer didn't really cover the approach you where looking for.

```
With the use of a function and Call arguments, you can define what you want to 
happen with input.

As an alternative to writing set /p Varname= If-Do/Goto IfNot Do/Goto whenever
you want input, Use:

CALL :Get_Input example hello1 Hello1_Continue Hello1_Wrong compare
```

This defines the Variable to be assigned: "example"
The Desired value for the Variable: "hello1"
The label to Goto If Value is Correct: "Hello1_Continue"
The label to Goto If Value is Wrong: "Hello1_Wrong"
Instruct the function what action to perform: "compare"

The fifth parameter gives you the freedom to incorperate other actions to take depending on what your doing post input.

```
@ECHO OFF
::: Required:
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

::: Whenever you need input:
::: CALL :Get_Input VarName DefaultValue RightLabel WrongLabel InputAction

CALL :Get_Input example hello1 Hello1_Continue Hello1_Wrong compare
```

*** Input Assess Function ***

```
:Get_Input
Set VarName=%~1
Set %VarName%=
Set DefValue=%~2
Set Right_Label=%~3
Set Wrong_Label=%~4
Set InputAction=%~5
Set /p %VarName%=[option:]

IF NOT DEFINED !VarName! GOTO Get_Input

::: Other Validation Options Here

IF /I "%InputAction%" EQU "validate" Goto :EOF

IF /I "!%VarName%!" EQU "exit" Goto end

IF /I "!%VarName%!" EQU "!DefValue!" Goto %Right_Label%

::: Other comparison / Do Options Here

::: Options for other action types Here.

::: Other options need to occur before being forwarded to next label.
::: If Variable is something such as a name etc, use 'validate' as fifth 
::: parameter to validate it, and continue your program from there.

IF /I "%InputAction%" EQU "compare" Goto %Wrong_Label%

::: Other actions using the input.
GOTO :EOF
```

*** End Function ***

```
:Hello1_Continue
ECHO %example% is correct
pause >nul
GOTO docall

:Hello1_Wrong
ECHO %example% should be %DefValue%
pause >nul
GOTO docall

:next
ECHO Your Program Continues...
pause
GOTO docall

:end
exit
```